# How to use setScrollListener in StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I tried to add Scroll listener in StaggeredGridView
there i can't figure out a way to add that there is no implementations for that i can see
Github url
https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that inherits SwipeRefreshLayout and override canChildScrollUp() method to check if StaggeredGridView reached the top or not, if it reached the top return true else return false.

```
public class SwipeDownToRefrsh extends SwipeRefreshLayout{

PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView;

public SwipeDownToRefrsh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



public void canChildScrollUp (PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView) {
    this.pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView = pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView;
}


@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return !pullToRefreshStaggeredGridView.getRefreshableView().mGetToTop;
    }
}
```

}

In your Activity or Fragment just send the instant of your StaggeredGridView like this :

((SwipeDownToRefrsh)holder.swipeRefreshLayout).canChildScrollUp(holder.staggeredGridView);

Comment: its best not to use link only answers, as the links could expire leaving everyone to wonder what the solution was

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I tried to tackle the problem

First ,add a private instance :

```
private AbsListView.OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;
```

Add public setOnClickListener method :

```
public void setOnScrollListener (AbsListView.OnScrollListener l) {
    mOnScrollListener = l;
}
```

Then, in trackMotionScroll , add lines to invoke the listener:

```
private boolean trackMotionScroll(int deltaY, boolean allowOverScroll) {
.
.
.

/* HERE we call onScroll */
if (mOnScrollListener != null) {
    mOnScrollListener.onScroll(null, getFirstPosition(), getChildCount(), this.mItemCount);
}

return deltaY == 0 || movedBy != 0;
}
```

You can also implement your own `onScrollStateChanged (AbsListView view, int scrollState)`method, but I am too lazy to do so :P

Finally you can call `gridView.setOnScrollListener(listener)` to pass in a listener to StaggeredGridView

Hope it helps.

Comment: in StaggeredGridView they don't have method for this setOnScrollListener(listener)

Comment: You can edit the source and implement this method in the StaggeredGridView class, because the plugin itself really doesn't have that.

Comment: This is solution for scroll listener problem, answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and that's why I added the support for scroll listener myself you can find the project on github here: https://github.com/GoMino/StaggeredGridView

Comment: Nice fix @gomino. I´ve faced the same issue and I´ll be using your code for it. Thanks! ps: upvoted by the way.